# When I should use SASS for my projects?

Tags: css, sass

I'm learning [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) and now I'm only reading sometings about it. When I should use it in my projects?

Is there some tricks about it? For example,

If lines of CSS file(s) are more than X,
If small,medium,large project,
If there are more than X class, field, id etc.

Because now I'm using only CSS3 for my projects and it seems enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Because SASS compiles to CSS, it cannot style to any greater degree than will normal CSS.

The reason to use SASS is to structure your stylesheets. SASS allows you to use mixins, variables, and functions, which allow you to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't repeat yourself) up your code.

Answer (score 0):

In the beggining with precompilers like Sass I used only minimum of functionality like nesting, variables , imports , some mixins. 
Preprocessors don't learn you to write better code, it only ease the structuring , organization and can help you DRY your code.
Allways check output when you starting with preprocessors because you can bloat your CSS if you are not careful enough. 
I use Sass in all project big and small and my favourite functionality is importing.